# Inquiry on Rudin's proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking at page 2 of Rudin's principles of real analysis on the proof there is no rational number $p$ such that $p^2 = 2.$

Why must $m$ and $n$ be odd?

And why does $m^2$ being even or odd imply that $m$ is even or odd?

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 0):

The proof goes this way, say $p=\frac{m}{n}$. You can presume without loss of generality that they are coprime (to simplify the case where, for example, $p=2=\frac{4}{2}$ and thus). So being coprime means that their GCD is $1$. If they were both even, then their GCD wouldn't be $1$.

Furthermore, since $2=p^2=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$ then that means
$$m^2=2\cdot n^2$$ this means that $m$ is even due to prime decomposition (if there weren't any $2$'s in $m$'s decomposition, then $m^2$ wouldn't be divisible by $2$). But now, since we know that $m$ is in fact divisible by two, then we also get that $m^2$ is divisible by $2^2$ (one $2$ for each $m$ in the product, at least). However, since $m^2=2\cdot n^2$ then the other $2$ should be in $n$'s decomposition, but that would mean $n$ is even and $m$ is even, which is a contradiction to our coprime supposition.

**Comment:** This is not your first question on the site, so I would highly recommend you read question standards. The proof for the irrationality of the square root of two is standard enough for me to get what $m$ and $n$ are, but that is completely unclear from your question.